# Compressed DataBase Backup in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to take Compressed Backup of my Databases in SQL Server 2008 on daily basis automatically. I know how to take backup, but don't know how to take compressed backup to save disk space. is there any easy way, to take compressed backup, as i have searched on web but mostly found sql queries and stored procedures to take compressed backup. 
Also i want to know , if compressed backup have any drawbacks please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do it by wizard. then
then follow this link http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/create-a-maintenance-backup-plan-in-sql-server-2008-r2-using-the-wizard

NOTE: you have to change the default option of SET BACKUP COMPRESSION to COMPRESSED BACKUP.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Visit the following links, it will really help you

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/03/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-new-feature-of-backup-compression/

or

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3716561/BACKUP-compression-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use this query,

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDB 
TO DISK = 'D:\MyDBBackup.bak' 
WITH COMPRESSION ;
```

or Follow these two links,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964719.aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964719(v=sql.100).aspx

you will get complete guidance over here,

Comment: thanks , but is there any wizard or something to do the same job?

Comment: A backup wizard exist but there is no way to backup in compress format via vizard.

Comment: Thumbup if this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I use compressed backups and i never han any problem with it.
The data backed up is EXACTLY the same, even the logs, and the size is less.